# Can't git push due to "remote: fatal: bad object refs/pull-requests/{pull_request_id}"

Tags: git

I clone a private repo then create a `test` branch from `master` and push it unsuccessfully.

Here is the command output:

```
$ git push --set-upstream origin test
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: fatal: bad object refs/pull-requests/101/v2
fatal: bad object refs/pull-requests/101/v2
To ssh://git.my_repo_host:9999/my_repo.git
 ! [remote rejected]   test -> test (missing necessary objects)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git.my_repo_host:9999/my_repo.git'
```

I also tried `git fsck --full` and `git gc` but no luck:

```
$ git fsck --full
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (31288/31288), done.
Verifying commits in commit graph: 100% (4081/4081), done.

$ git gc
Enumerating objects: 31288, done.
Counting objects: 100% (31288/31288), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (13738/13738), done.
Writing objects: 100% (31288/31288), done.
Total 31288 (delta 15511), reused 31274 (delta 15505), pack-reused 0
```

And this is the output of `git config --local -l` on master branch, nothing special here.

```
$ git config --local -l
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
remote.origin.url=ssh://git@git.my_repo_host:9999/my_repo.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

## Final Update

The git data on my remote repo host has been **corrupted** after the IT team did maintenance recently. It backs to normal after their fix.
Sorry, No more detail (how did they fixed) from them.

Comment: What does `git gc` return? (when executed inside your local repository)

Comment: @VonC, I added the output to my question

Comment: And I suppose the issue persists after `fcsk`/`gc`? Can you include your `git config --local -l`?

Comment: @VonC, I added. But no special config from my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is coming from the Git software on `git.my_repo_host`, indicating that there is a problem in the repository at `ssh://git.my_repo_host:9999/my_repo.git`.  We can tell because of this line:

```
remote: fatal: bad object refs/pull-requests/101/v2
```

The word `remote` here means your Git software is relaying a message generated by the other host's software.

So, it is the *remote* repository that needs to be repaired or replaced.  Your own local repository is OK.

Find the administrators of `git.my_repo_host` and have them fix the other machine's repository.

Comment: I confirmed that nothing was wrong with my local repo. After asking our repo maintainer to fix the remote git repo database. It's working now. No more detail because they fixed it on their side.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you diagnosed the problem from the line that begins with `remote: fatal:`. It tells that the error was produced on the remote side.

Comment: @j6t: good point, I'll note that above.

Comment: i am having this error and in my case the remote is github, not sure what to do in that case :(

Answer (score -2):

```bash
rm .git/refs/remotes/origin/master

git fetch
```

Comment: Code only answers are not very useful. Please edit your answer and add some details about what this code does and why it fixes OP's problem.